# MySQL, storing large number of records

Tags: mysql, database

I'm designing a shop model with a database that stores a list of sold products. What is most effective way to do this?  Keeping everything in one table seems wrong because after a year it would have billions of records. Is it okay to create a new table each day?

Comment: This is a potentially very complex situation. All I know is you probably should not be creating a new table every day for whatever it was you were planning to do with it.

Comment: It will work, but not a good idea.  Your store sells billions of items a year?  That would be a milestone itself but I doubt it.  MySQL can handle millions of rows with ease if the table is properly indexed.  If you truly have billions of rows, I would suspect the smartest thing to do would be to have an archive table after a certain point.

Comment: @Devon I just want to make something like this just for learning purposes, however I was wondering how it looks like in real shop and I would like to make my database accordingly to that.

Comment: The answer is probably to [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) your table... but don't bother even attempting that until you have actually sold a few hundred million products—by then you should be able to employ a MySQL DBA who'll make sure the partitioning is done sensibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your store will actually sell billions of itens a day you either partition your table or create a Schedule that runs for example every month and archive the the items that are older than month in another table.

When requesting the data the purchases older than 30-days check the archive table, and the recent ones in the default table. Not sure how this would actually perform but for most stores even a Single table with both purchases should work well.